# How to plot absolute values and differences including confidence intervals

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, lattice

In the followup of the discussion on [stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60767/how-to-display-error-bars-for-cross-over-paired-experiments/60793?noredirect=1#60793) I tried to implement the following plot

[image: Cumming Finch Plot] from

Cumming, G., & Finch, S. (2005). [Inference by Eye: Confidence Intervals and How to Read Pictures of Data][5]. *American Psychologist*, 60(2), 170–180. doi:10.1037/0003-066X.60.2.170

I share some people's dislike of double axis, but I think this is a fair use.

Below my partial attempt, the second axis is still missing. I am looking for more elegant alternatives, intelligent variations are welcome.

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
d = data.frame(what=c("A","B","Difference"), 
               mean=c(75,105,30),
               lower=c(50,80,-3),
               upper = c(100,130,63))

# Convert Differences to left scale
d1 = d
d1[d1$what=="Difference",-1] = d1[d1$what=="Difference",-1]+d1[d1=="A","mean"]

segplot(what~lower+upper,centers=mean,data=d1,horizontal=FALSE,draw.bands=FALSE,
        lwd=3,cex=3,ylim=c(0,NA),pch=c(16,16,17),
        panel = function (x,y,z,...){
          centers = list(...)$centers
          panel.segplot(x,y,z,...)
          panel.abline(h=centers[1:2],lty=3)
        } )
## How to add the right scale, close to the last bar?
```

[image]

Comment: In your code, I think you need to load the `latticeExtra` package to get the `segplot()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
par(mar=c(3,5,3,5))
plot(NA, xlim=c(.5,3.5), ylim=c(0, max(d$upper[1:2])), bty="l", xaxt="n", xlab="",ylab="Mean")
points(d$mean[1:2], pch=19)
segments(1,d$mean[1],5,d$mean[1],lty=2)
segments(2,d$mean[2],5,d$mean[2],lty=2)
axis(1, 1:3, d$what)
segments(1:2,d$lower[1:2],1:2,d$upper[1:2])
axis(4, seq((d$mean[1]-30),(d$mean[1]+50),by=10), seq(-30,50,by=10), las=1)
points(3,d$mean[1]+d$mean[3],pch=17, cex=1.5)
segments(3,d$lower[3]+d$lower[2],3,d$lower[3]+d$upper[2], lwd=2)
mtext("Difference", side=4, at=d$mean[1], line=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Base graphics lovers abound. This looks really good. Probably the dashed lines should go as in the original plot (mine is wrong), and I would shift the second axis a bit more to the right.

Comment: Horizontal lines are easy to kill, and if you want the axis moved slightly, I would just change the upper limit of `xlim` in `plot`, which should leave everything else the same.

Comment: This is as close to the original as one could come. However, I am still thinking of ways to make evident at first sight that one is difference, the other absolute. Maybe better position the second axis left to the difference bar?

Comment: I think I would offset the difference bar slightly (position it at 3.5 instead of 3) and set its `lwd=2`. You might also consider setting either the left or right axis to gray to highlight one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

As a starting point another base R solution with Hmisc:

```
library(Hmisc)

with(d1,
     errbar(as.integer(what),mean,upper,lower,xlim=c(0,4),xaxt="n",xlab="",ylim=c(0,150))
     )
points(3,d1[d1$what=="Difference","mean"],pch=15)
axis(1,at=1:3,labels=d1$what)
atics <- seq(floor(d[d$what=="Difference","lower"]/10)*10,ceiling(d[d$what=="Difference","upper"]/10)*10,by=10)
axis(4,at=atics+d1[d1=="A","mean"],labels=atics,pos=3.5)
```

[image]

Comment: The presence of 0 on the extra axis is important.

Answer (score 3):

I would also go with base graph, as it includes the possibility to actually have two y-axis, see [the answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1838/442):

Here is my soultion that uses only `d`:

```
xlim <- c(0.5, 3.5)

plot(1:2, d[d$what %in% LETTERS[1:2], "mean"], xlim = xlim, ylim = c(0, 140), 
    xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt = "n", bty = "l", yaxs = "i")
lines(c(1,1), d[1, 3:4])
lines(c(2,2), d[2, 3:4])

par(new = TRUE)
plot(3, d[d$what == "Difference", "mean"], ylim = c(-80, 130), xlim = xlim, 
    yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "n")
lines(c(3,3), d[3, 3:4])
Axis(x = c(-20, 60), at = c(-20, 0, 20, 40, 60), side = 4)
axis(1, at = c(1:3), labels = c("A", "B", "Difference"))
```

Which gives:
[image]

To make it clearer that the difference is something different, you can increase the distance from the other two points:

```
xlim <- c(0.5, 4)
plot(1:2, d[d$what %in% LETTERS[1:2], "mean"], xlim = xlim, ylim = c(0, 140), 
    xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt = "n", bty = "l", yaxs = "i")
lines(c(1,1), d[1, 3:4])
lines(c(2,2), d[2, 3:4])

par(new = TRUE)
plot(3.5, d[d$what == "Difference", "mean"], ylim = c(-80, 130), xlim = xlim, 
    yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "n")
lines(c(3.5,3.5), d[3, 3:4])
Axis(x = c(-20, 60), at = c(-20, 0, 20, 40, 60), side = 4)
axis(1, at = c(1,2,3.5), labels = c("A", "B", "Difference"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that paper. I will report back on stackexchange after I found a good solution.

Comment: You probably need to play around with the positioning of the second y-axis (done via the second `ylim` argument). And I am always glad to help with pointers to literature I liked.

Comment: I am not sure if your solution (axis on box) or the original one is better. I like the L-form of the graphics in the paper with the unorthodox positioning of the axis; it is a pointer that there is something special. @Thomas comes closest.

Comment: In base R everything is possible! The changes are the use of the `bty` arguments to `plot` and the call to the `Axis` function (with captial A) instead of `axis`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that also with base R, what about:

```
d = data.frame(what=c("A","B","Difference"), 
               mean=c(75,105,30),
               lower=c(50,80,-3),
               upper = c(100,130,63))

plot(-1,-1,xlim=c(1,3),ylim=c(0,140),xaxt="n")

lines(c(1,1),c(d[1,3],d[1,4]))
points(rep(1,3),d[1,2:4],pch=4)

lines(c(1.5,1.5),c(d[2,3],d[2,4]))
points(rep(1.5,3),d[2,2:4],pch=4)

lines(c(2,2),c(d[3,3],d[3,4]))
points(rep(2,3),d[3,2:4],pch=4)

lines(c(1.5,2.2),c(d[2,2],d[2,2]),lty="dotted")

axis(1, at=c(1,1.5,2), labels=c("A","B","Difference"))
axis(4,at=c(40,80,120),labels=c(-1,0,1),pos=2.2)
```

I simplified some things and didn't wrote it as function, but I think the idea is clear and could easily be extended to a function.

Comment: Yes, base plot is fine, and it is easy to use a second axis with it. I am a bit latticish, because I hope to be able to used it with panels.

Comment: The difference is placed incorrectly, but it could be easily changed by using my derived d1 data set instead of d

Comment: Uh, maybe I picked the wrong items from `d`, I thought to write lines that symbolize the idea, hence I haven't checked if the output makes sense, as I thought when it suits you, you have to adjust it anyway. And sorry to ask, but what do you mean by "use it with panels"? I haven't used lattice so far, so I am a bit confused what is the advantage of it.

Comment: "With panels" (or "with facets" in ggplot): Automatically arrange multiple similar plots with headers in a grid. It's the best feature of lattice and ggplot, so try it!